# Ionic Setup development environment

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 1 and I am trying to build an Ionic app on the Android emulator.

When running this command: `ionic platform add android`

I get this error :

```
Adding android project...


Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

    Path: platforms/android

    Package: com.ionicframework.myapp543129

    Name: myApp

    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-24


cp: dest file no such file or directory: platforms/android/assets
```

I already installed cordova, and android studio.
How do I fix this error?

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: is it a problem with permissions of the folder?

Comment: I don't think so, I just created the project using the command : `ionic start myApp sidemenu`

Comment: When I removed it and runned the same command, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally removed the project and created another one with the same name (it was only a hello world project)
And it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm is a permission error.

I had this folder inside the Dropbox folder and I had the same error.
Try moving the root project folder somewhere else o fix permissions and you'll have it working fine.

Comment: I did, but the same problem (I think it related to package name)